# Google Cloud Dataflow error: "The Application Default Credentials are not available"

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

We have a Google Cloud Dataflow job, which writes to Bigtable (via HBase API). Unfortunately, it fails due to:

`java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information. at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:74) at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:54) at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.config.CredentialFactory.getApplicationDefaultCredential(CredentialFactory.java:181) at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.config.CredentialFactory.getCredentials(CredentialFactory.java:100) at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.grpc.io.CredentialInterceptorCache.getCredentialsInterceptor(CredentialInterceptorCache.java:85) at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.grpc.BigtableSession.<init>(BigtableSession.java:257) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableConnection.<init>(AbstractBigtableConnection.java:123) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AbstractBigtableConnection.<init>(AbstractBigtableConnection.java:91) at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_0.BigtableConnection.<init>(BigtableConnection.java:33) at com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow.CloudBigtableConnectionPool$1.<init>(CloudBigtableConnectionPool.java:72) at com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow.CloudBigtableConnectionPool.createConnection(CloudBigtableConnectionPool.java:72) at com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow.CloudBigtableConnectionPool.getConnection(CloudBigtableConnectionPool.java:64) at com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow.CloudBigtableConnectionPool.getConnection(CloudBigtableConnectionPool.java:57) at com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow.AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn.getConnection(AbstractCloudBigtableTableDoFn.java:96) at com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow.CloudBigtableIO$CloudBigtableSingleTableBufferedWriteFn.getBufferedMutator(CloudBigtableIO.java:836) at com.google.cloud.bigtable.dataflow.CloudBigtableIO$CloudBigtableSingleTableBufferedWriteFn.processElement(CloudBigtableIO.java:861)`

Which makes very little sense, because the job is already running on Cloud Dataflow service/VMs.

The Cloud Dataflow job id: `2016-05-13_11_11_57-8485496303848899541`

We are using `bigtable-hbase-dataflow` version `0.3.0`, and we want to use HBase API.

Comment: Is it possible that you don't have the credentials set in gcloud on the machine that is starting the Dataflow job??

Comment: gcloud beta auth application-default print-access-token    or  application-default login        to fix.

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel Should it have default service account then? Also those VMs are started by the DF service.

Comment: Ben's answer looks like the issue, if not, I was trying to ask, on what machine do you start the dataflow service?

Comment: @ravwojdyla — was this issue resolved for you with the 1.6.0 release of Dataflow? If so, please accept the answer below; if not, please post an update with the issues you are seeing, whether it's the same or new errors.

Comment: @MishaBrukman let me still observe dataflow a bit more, the nature of the error was that it did not appear for every run, will update if there is anything new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a known issue where GCE instances are very rarely unable to get the default credentials during startup.

We have been working on a fix which should be part of the next release (1.6.0) which should be coming soon. In the meantime we'd suggest re-submitting the job which should work. If you run into problems consistently or want to discuss other workarounds (such as backporting the 1.6.0 fix) please reach out to us.

Answer (score 0):

1.7.0 is released so this should be fixed now https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-java